# Stop Javascript from kicking off on back button

Tags: javascript, pdf-generation

Main Form:

Calling from code behind, for a dropdown list box, I create a url to generate a PDF, and to close that form(PDFGenerator), which then returns back to MainForm:

```
string redirect = "<script>window.open('/pdfgenerator/BL/" + customerdocument.DocumentId');</script>";
this.Response.Write(redirect);
```

The pdfgenerator creates the pdf, and then closes this webpage automatically'

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
pdfFileStream.CopyTo(HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
HttpContext.Current.Response.SuppressContent = true;
HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream.Flush();
HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream.Close();
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

Now when I am on the default/main page, and navigate to any other page, and hit the back button, the pdfgenerator page pops back up and generates another pdf, even though the dropdown was not clicked. I tried to set up breakpoints to see if there was any javascript on the main page that was calling to kick this off (there wasn't). And I looked at the referring page on the PDF Generator (which states the main page, and not the page I just hit the back button from). Anyone know what this is? And how to stop it? Or unload the javascript somehow so it doesn't get called again on the back button?

Answer (score 0):

We ended up removing the c# code behind and went with straight javascript. No postback is being called now (of course).